# Request failed with status code 404 (REDUX)

Tags: reactjs, redux

Can't seem to pull data from database but according Redux DevTools the actions PASSWORD_LIST_REQUEST seems to be firing. What is going wrong here? I checked my original route, it should be going towards "api/passwords" in the server, is this a backend problem or Redux problem?

I checked the backend url routes with postman, so thats all good.

ACTIONS

```
export const listPasswords = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PASSWORD_LIST_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/passwords");

    dispatch({
      type: PASSWORD_LIST_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PASSWORD_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

REDUCERS

```
  export const passwordListReducer = (state = { passwords: [] }, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case PASSWORD_LIST_REQUEST:
          return {
            loading: true,
            passwords: [],
          };
        case PASSWORD_LIST_SUCCESS:
          return { passwords: action.payload, loading: false };
        case PASSWORD_LIST_FAIL:
          return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

STORE

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { passwordListReducer } from "./reducers/passwordReducers";

const reducer = combineReducers({ passwordList: passwordListReducer });

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

Server

```
import passwordRoutes from "./routes/passwordRoutes.js";

dotenv.config();

connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("API is running");
});

app.use("/api/passwords", passwordRoutes);

app.use(notFound);

app.use(errorHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`)
);
```

Comment: Does the app and backend run on the same port/domain?

Comment: Server runs on 5000. Front end/ client runs on 3000.

Comment: If so you should call the api service as `http://localhost:5000/api/passwords`

Comment: in the server file?

Comment: You can take a look at my answer @ToanLam

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your call to endpoint might be going to the wrong url here

```
const { data } = await axios.get("/api/passwords");
```

The above axios call would point to your app url, say you app is running on localhost:3000, an API call would be made to `http://localhost:3000/api/password` by default.

If your app and back end run on different ports on your localhost, you have to set the domain on the axios call. From you code sample, I see you set you APIs to run from port 5000.

```
const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/passwords");
```

**Tip**

If you don't want to keep repeating the base url, you can create an axios instance

```
export const request = axios.create({baseUrl: "http://localhost:5000"});
```

Then make your requests this way

```
import { request } from "path to request module";

...
const { data } = await request.get("/api/passwords");
...
```

Comment: I'm getting "Network Error" now

Comment: Using this `const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/passwords");` ?

Comment: yes, i guess i just have to re do it from scratch again.

Comment: Alright. Also check if the request is hitting your endpoint

Comment: the endpoint works, but I cannot pull "passwords" from "passwordList" through useSelector

Answer (score 0):

I needed a proxy in package.json.

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```